# How does a NodeJS app with multiple timers scale?

Tags: node.js, performance, timer, scaling

My app will require up to 1000 timers at any given moment. Do timers consume a lot of resources? Is it an accepted practice to deploy multiple timers? Or should I avoid it?

Comment: It would take about 10 lines of code to write a quick test for 10,000 timers each set for a slightly different time and see how well it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **@jfriend00**'s suggestion, i made a sample check below, this might be not accurate (cuz of dom manipulations), but hope it gives you concept

```js
// let's use 2 measurings, window.performance.now and console.time

// start console.time, usually it gives same result as window.perf.now
// but window.perf.now uses 10 decimal points
console.time('timer_perf_test');
var now1 = window.performance.now();

// our count, this test really lags when 100,000
// CHANGE THIS 
var count = 10000;

// some dom elements for text
var elem = document.querySelector('img');
var counter = document.querySelector('#counter');
var perf = document.querySelector('#perf');

// how smooth our image gonna rotate?
var rotate = function(degree){
    elem.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degree +'deg)';
    counter.textContent = 'timers executed: ' + degree;
}

// create bunch of timers with different timeout
var timer = function(added_time){
    setTimeout(function(){
     rotate(added_time);
    }, 1000 + (added_time * 10));
}
// test begins
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    timer(i)
}

// check results
var now2 = window.performance.now();
perf.textContent = now2 - now1 + ' MS required to create ' + count + ' timers';
console.timeEnd('timer_perf_test');
```

```html
<img src="https://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT4211/HT4211-ios7-activity_icon-001-en.png" width="100" height="100">
<p id="counter"></p>
<p id="perf"></p>
```